# Why does isset($_GET['code']) returning false while using google oauth login in php?

Tags: php, oauth, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

```
 include ("header.php") ;
    require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/ecommerce/index.php');
    $client->addScope('email');
    $client->addScope('profile');
    $login_button=' <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
        <a class="btn  btn-social btn-google" href="'.$client->createAuthUrl().'" role="button">
            <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
            Sign in with Google
        </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>';

 if(isset($_GET['code'])){
     
     $token=$client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
     if(!isset($token['error'])){
         $client->setAccessToken($token['access_token']);
         $_SESSION['access_token']=$token['access_token'];
         $google_service=new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
         $data=$google_service->userinfo->get();
         if(!empty($data['given_name'])){
             $_SESSION['uid']=$data['given_name'];
         }
         if(!empty($data['family_name'])){
            $_SESSION['user_last_name']=$data['family_name'];
        }
        if(!empty($data['gender'])){
            $_SESSION['gender']=$data['gender'];
        }
     }
 }


 ?>
```

My code does not enter the if block: isset($_GET['code']) is returning false.
I want access to just the user name and gender.
I have installed composer and google api client 2.0.

Comment: Your IF condition is returning false because there is no 'code' parameter in the GET request! Make a request appending "?code" in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Its not set probably because you haven't called auth yet.  Code is only set after the user has clicked the consent screen and then it will never ben used again.

[oauth2callback.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Gmail%20API/v1/oauth2callback.php)

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/Oauth2Authentication.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client = buildClient();
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client = buildClient();
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); // Exchange the authencation code for a refresh token and access token.
    // Add access token and refresh token to seession.
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $_SESSION['refresh_token'] = $client->getRefreshToken();    
    //Redirect back to main script
    $redirect_uri = str_replace("oauth2callback.php",$_SESSION['mainScript'],$client->getRedirectUri());    
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

?>
```

[Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Gmail%20API/v1/Oauth2Authentication.php)

```
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {
        
        $client = buildClient();
        
        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }
        
        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            
            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 
            
            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```